# Como resolver o problema do PHP 5.6 com PPA obsoleto no Linux?

Tags: php, linux, deprecated

Fui rodar o comando `sudo apt-get upgrade` e recebi a mensagem de descontinuação da PPA do PHP.

Depois de atualizar a versão do PHP, quando executo `php -v`, aparece o seguinte:

```
 PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
```

Nesse caso,se essa PPA está obsoleto, o que devo fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Boa pergunta, reparei agora que o meu também está assim. Gostaria de resolver também

Comment: Pois é. Inclusive prepare-se, pois os diretórios de configuração do PHP foram **totalmente alterados**. O que ficava em `/etc/php5` agora foi parar em `/etc/php/5.6`

Comment: Cuidado que no meu, alguns laravel que eu tinha ficaram partidos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O repositório foi alterado conforme pode verificar nessa [nota](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5). Adicione o

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

e atualize a `apt-list`:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Depois só instalar a versão desejada `5.5`, `5.6`, `7.0`, 7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
```

Comment: Atualizado, @WallaceMaxters